# Event getting cut ( visible ) near 00:00

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using FullCalendar v.3.4.0 with no CSS changes.

**I have only the base css and the print version declared.**

As you can see on the picture, the last event, that starts near midnight, is getting cut visually.

In Fullcalendar's Github, there is a sticky issue regarding Chrome's rendering of the table, but I'm not sure if the problem lies there.

I haven't tried Firefox, but I'm running this in a webview of a Cordova app on Android, so i'm bound to Chrome.

[example of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObT3a.png)

Init code

```js
    $('#events').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        allDaySlot: false,
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: true,      
        displayEventTime: true,
        header: {
           left: 'prev,next today',
           center: 'title',
           right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
        },
        events: "remote.php"
   }
```

Can I add a "ghost" event so it pushes the overflowed view in order to see that event? I would like avoid jquerying my way into the DOM, but if there is no other change I will do so.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards

Comment: This is a pretty old version of fullCalendar now...any reason for not using the latest version? It might potentially fix the bug, and it certainly fixes other bugs and provides new features and better performance

Comment: Current version uses jQuery dependency and I am still evaluating the whole application's upgrade path, since it relies heavily in the calendar.

Comment: Just because fullCalendar no longer requires jQuery doesn't mean you can't continue to use it in the rest of your code. That should be a relatively minor problem in your upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved with the following steps:

**Backend**

Added a field called "time" ( or any field you wish to use ) and whenever you detect the end date goes to the next day you set "time" to "23-59".

**Frontend**

Add the following code to your Fullcalendar init:

```js
    eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {                    
        if (eventObj.time == "23-59") {
            $($el).css({"overflow":"inherit","height":"50px"});                            
        }
    },
    eventAfterAllRender : function (view) {
        if (view.type == 'agendaDay') {                        
            $(".fc-agendaDay-view .fc-slats table tbody").append('<tr>\
            <td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="height:100px"></td>\
            <td class="fc-widget-content">&nbsp;</td>\
            </tr>');
        }                    
    }
```

This is not an elegant solution for v3 but it suits my requirements.